# How to add existing kubernetes menifest files to Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to Helm Chart I have few menifest files .yaml which are running seprate on same server I want to combine them all using Helm Chart so I dont have to manage them seprately,
so far i have tried and seen lots of Articles where peoples are creating Helm Chart and Basics etc but never found a way or guide where i can use my existing menifest .yaml file with Helm Chart any help or guidance highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Helm charts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) are made up of files in the `templates` directory that are run through a go templating process.

```
helm create mychart
rm mychart/templates/*.yaml
mv mymanifests/* mychart/templates/
```

Plain yaml will work in there, but you will want to replace a number of values with the helm `{{ template }}` equivalents.

Comment: this step is already done i forget to mentioned i am totally new to Helm Chart and the values which needs to change right after moving microservices yaml files into the template folder but which values needs to change to make it work. i have multiple microservices some of them depended on each other and some are stand alone.

Comment: @MuhammadZaman if you have specific issues then provide the specific templates and values you want to use

Comment: @MuhammadZaman I should also add the initial templates are the best place to start for a deploy, merge your yaml config into those initial templates rather than starting from scratch

Comment: i am not been able to find any initial template i found some code from stackoverflow questions and run loop over 10 microservice to create a pods but unable to create 10 container with different ports if you want to see the code let me know i'll put it here